# Selecting a node if the attribute is equal to a predefined string

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I'm currently using a loop which gives me a variable, which then needs to be fed into an Xpath method to get me any nodes with an attribute equal to my variable. So far, I've learned that Xpath allows you to select a node from the XML document using

```
root.SelectNodes("Element[@Attribute='SpecificValue']")
```

However, I'd like to know if there's a way I can insert a predefined variable where the specific value, so I can grab a different set of nodes with each iteration of my loop.

For example something like this:

```
string  attribValue= "test"
root.SelectNodes("Element[@Attribute = attribValue]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [string formatting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string attribValue = "test";
string expression = String.Format("Element[@Attribute = '{0}']", attribValue);
root.SelectNodes(expression);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using XML Linq

```css
            XDocument doc = new XDocument();
            XElement root = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            string  attribValue= "test";
            var results = root.Descendants("Element").Where(x => x.Attribute("Attribute").Value == attribValue).ToList();​
```